# EMR notebooks template for cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I am aware of AWS cloudformation EMR resource to create Clusters. But, I could not find any instructions about EMR notebooks. Is there a cloudformation resource for EMR notebooks or similar alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EMR Notebooks can only be created manually using the AWS EMR console. From the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-create.html):

> You create an EMR notebook using the Amazon EMR console. Creating notebooks using the AWS CLI or the Amazon EMR API is not supported.

Since there is no API for this I don't think there will be a way to create notebooks using CloudFormation or similar tools.